# Filling Postgres table gaps with oldest available value

Tags: postgresql, time-series

I am trying to fill the missing colored rows with the earliest value which remains valid until a new value is set using SQL queries in Postgres database

[image: Sample table and data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first_value()` like this:

```
select 
    client, 
    activity_date,
    val,
    first_value(val) over (partition by client, grp_t) as new_val
from (
      select client, activity_date, val,
             sum(case when val is not null then 1 end) over (order by client, activity_date) as grp_t
      from   filling
) t
order by 1,2,3;
```

[image]

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6085d31203a48117c5eead28354e1cb5) example

**upd.** Fixed new_val due to issue when the first row per client is NULL

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, however there is strange behavior when the client changes, see the first row for 2021-03-01 for client ID 2, how can that be set to null

Comment: @StephenSenkomagoMusoke got it, check the fixed code in my answer